# Is there a way to match words to sentences inside a html <b> tag in PHP

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

So i have this code to extract the text between in b tags.

```
$source_url = "https://www.wordpress.com/";
$html = file_get_contents($source_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('b');
$words = "php"; 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($dom);
echo "</pre>";
```

I tried to put the text inside in an array using array_push and others but if im going to use in_array
i need to put the whole sentence to return true not only a word.

So what i want exactly is :

If that sentence contains 'php' then return true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
foreach($links as $link) {
    $p = strtolower($link->nodeValue);
    if (strpos($p, 'php') !== false) {
        // do something

    }
}
```

Comment: try to print $links to sure that it is not null

Comment: It's not null,everytime i try it it just return true. I tried with words that doesn't exists returns true,tried words that exists return true again.. tried on my own website.

Comment: I found it why >= 0 should be >= 1 with this it's working fine. Thanks for helping

Comment: Good. Please try with !== false

Comment: It's working fine also with !== false, thanks for helping

Comment: ----De nada----